# htaccess redirect .asp page but allow same page with variables to serve

Tags: .htaccess, isapi-rewrite

using htaccess (isapi) I need to redirect .asp page but leave .asp page WITH variables untouched. This sounds simple and so I thought it was but my efforts have been fruitless.

```
RewriteRule ^CodePage.asp$ ^NewCodePage.asp? [R=301,NC,L]
```

I want to match EXPLICITLY that exact URL to the new Root Landing page but leave all dynamic pages served from CodePage.asp untouched.

```
e.g. http://www.domain.com/CodePage.asp?prodid=666
```

I thought the '$' sign would achieve this but the rule is matching ALL full path dynamic pages as well and pushing them to the NewCodePage.asp page. Note, I do not want to pass the variables to the new page, just the root landing page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^CodePage\.asp$ NewCodePage.asp [R=301,NC]
```